# AWS Lambda C++ Runtime Permission Denied

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-linux

So I am trying to invoke a lambda that I deployed using the C++ runtime. I use the AWS CLI to invoke the function and as a response I get an error containing:

```
Runtime failed to start: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: permission denied <nil> <nil>
```

I have packaged everything in a way that I have used before with other functions that work so this is really unexpected for me. I am also building all of my code in an Amazon Linux Docker Container using g++. Any idea on what the source of the problem may be would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Out on a limb I think you might have packaged the binary such that it removed the `execute` permissions.

Try `chmod +x main`

Comment: Yeah somehow the bootstrap script did not have execute permissions. Changing that made it work